# UICollectionView Video Performance

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, avplayer, apple-tv

I have a UICollectionView for Apple TV. There are at most 6 cells all displaying on the same screen. Each cell has a different looping video playing. However, I find that anymore than 2 videos causing very choppy video playback. How can I improve performance of the playing videos?

```
class ExerciseCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet private weak var stationNumberLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet private weak var exerciseNameLabel: UILabel!

private var looperPlayer:AVPlayerLooper!

var exercise:ExerciseData! {
    didSet {
        self.stationNumberLabel.text = exercise.stationNumber
        self.exerciseNameLabel.text = exercise.exerciseName
        playVideo()
    }
}

private func playVideo()
{
    //if let videoURL = URL(string:self.exercise.videoURL)
    if let videoPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: self.exercise.videoName, ofType: "mp4")
    {
        //let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videoURL)
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath))
        let queuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: queuePlayer)

        playerLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds
        playerLayer.videoGravity = .resize
        playerLayer.player = queuePlayer

        self.looperPlayer = AVPlayerLooper(player: queuePlayer, templateItem: playerItem)
        self.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, at: 0)

        queuePlayer.volume = 0.0
        queuePlayer.play()
    }
    else
    {
        self.layer.sublayers?.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperlayer() }
    }
}}
```

The above is called from the `UICollectionViewController`

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ExerciseCell

    cell.exercise = self.exercisesArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the resolution of the source videos which were 1920X1080. Decreasing the resolution solved the problem.